# Border Around an Image When Tapped

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-runtime

I have an Image control. When the image is clicked at runtime it should be added to a grid as a child. I have implemented this.

My requirement now is when the image (which is now inside a grid) is tapped I need a border around the image. How can I achieve this?

I have added the following code inside image tapped but cannot see the border

```
Border b = new Border(); 
b.BorderThickness = new Thickness(4); 
img1 = new Image(); 
img1.MaxHeight = 300; 
img1.MaxWidth = 500; 
b.Child = img1; 
img1.Source = new BitmapImage((new Uri(imgPath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)));
grid1.Children.Add(b);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of droping the image as a grid cell child, create a Border object and put the image inside as a content.

Initially, the border can have BorderBrush transparent and thickness = 1 or other. Then, add the Tapped event to the image to modify the border brush color.

Based in your code above, you need something like

```
img1.Tapped += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((sender as Image).Parent as Border).BorderBrush = Brushes.Blue;
});
```

Comment: I think using the [Tapped](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.tapped.aspx) event, rather than MouseEnter and MouseLeave, would match more closely with what the OP is asking.

Comment: I improved my answer accordingly